# Would a second _trackPageview cause a 0% bounce rate?

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics, would a second push of the same `_trackPageview` on the same page cause the bounce rate to drop to 0% ?

Does this count the first 'visit' as having engaged to the same page since they 'visited' the same page again?

Any official documentation to explain this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess:

Since they are within the same ‘visit’ (session), and ‘view’ more than one page (due to second _trackPageview) this would cause 0% bounce.

“ Bounce rate summarizes the percentage of **single-page** visits to your site. Visits summarizes the number of sessions on your site. ”

<sub>source: https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsDataCalculation?hl=en#dimensionsAndMetrics</sub>

Comment: Easy to test it yourself. But the answer is yes.